# Cannot Deploy And Run Nativescript code Into Emulator and Samsung Device

Tags: android, android-emulator, nativescript

I'd like to ask about running android in nativescript :
i cannot run android app on emulator and samsung device (Galaxy Ace)

Command to run on emulator (both command is failed)

tns run android --emulator 
tns emulate android --avd AndroidEmulator

Command to run on Samsung Device

tns run android --device 7A89BB2E66674E44B6A6270F7F84XXX

But i can run for lennovo s920 , comand like below :

tns run android --device GAGEMZYL4P654XXX

I already set android sdk "platform-tools" and "tools" folder path into user varible on windows. and already configure samsung device to enable usb debugging

any ideas?

Comment: based on my research, I figure it out that nativescript only work on android 4.4.2 (Kit Kat), because I create new emulator nexus5 (Android 4.4.2) and run perfectly. anybody can explain to me why nativescript only working on android 442/API 19? 

.fyi, i already change min sdk version to 8 in android manifest and it's not resolved this problem.

Answer (score 0):

NativeScript support all Android version above Api17.

Can you try running command with `--log trace` option and paste the full log here.